# Convert NodeJs MySQL result to accessible JSON Object

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

I want to get some data from my database. Example:

```
  getCarIds: function (callback) {
    db.query("SELECT Id FROM Cars;",
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        result = JSON.stringify(result);

        var cars = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          var currentCar = result[i];
          var carId = currentCar.id;
          cars.push(carId);
        }

        callback(cars);
      });
  }
```

I want to store all the ids into an array. Like

```
cars = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

The result returns this

```
[ RowDataPacket { Id: '1' },
  RowDataPacket { Id: '2' },
  RowDataPacket { Id: '3' } ]
```

So I try to convert it by writing

```
result = JSON.stringify(result);
```

this returns me

```
[{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"2"},{"Id":"3"}]
```

when I want to access this object by writing

`result[0]`

I get

`[`

so obviously

```
result[0].id
```

will return

```
undefined
```

How can I get all the ids from the object?

Comment: you have to parse it, result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: also  try `JSON.Stringify(result[0].id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You don't need to `stringify` the `result`. Just Process the `result`
>   as it is.

and use `currentCar.Id` instead of `currentCar.id`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "just Process the `result`"?

Answer (score 15):

Say you have a result array of `RowDataPacket` from mysql called `results`. You can use Object.assign(). For example, if you wanted to convert the first element to a regular object:

```
var normalObj = Object.assign({}, results[0]);
```

or if you wanted the entire array converted to normal objects:

```
var normalResults = results.map((mysqlObj, index) => {
    return Object.assign({}, mysqlObj);
});
```

or more compact syntax:

```
results = results.map(v => Object.assign({}, v));
```